# Function for conditioned mean in SAS

Tags: sas, dataset, mean

I have a `dataset` which some cells are valorized with `888888888` and `999999999`. I would do the mean not considering these values. That is:

```
x=5, y=10, z=888888888
```

the mean will be 5.

How can I fix?

Answer (score 0):

As you're calculating across variables, just store them in an array, loop through them and sum any that are less than the required threshold (I've used 100,000,000), then divide by the total number of variables to get the mean.

```
data have;
input x y z;
datalines;
5 10 888888888
4 20 999999999
;
run;


data want;
set have;
array vars{*} x y z;
_sum=0;
do _i = 1 to dim(vars);
    if vars{_i}<1e8 then _sum+vars{_i};
end;
mean_vars = _sum/dim(vars);
drop _: ;
run;
```